# How to reset the background color of a widget to default state after using gtk_css_provider_load_from_data()

Tags: css, gtk3

I used to set and reset background colors of widgets via `gtk_widget_override_background_color`. This function is now deprecated, so I'd like to switch to using `GtkCssProvider`.

I know that I can change the background color of an entry field with for example

```
GtkCssProvider *provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (provider,
".entry { background: #927373}", -1, NULL);
gtk_style_context_add_provider (gtk_widget_get_style_context (entry_field),
GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

That's working fine. However, as before, under certain circumstances I'd like to revert the background color to default state.
Using

```
provider = gtk_css_provider_get_default ();
gtk_style_context_add_provider (gtk_widget_get_style_context (entry_field),
GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

doesn't have any effect, and using

```
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (provider,
".entry { background: #none}", -1, NULL);
```

is not the right way, since there is a default background color in the widget (for example white (dependent on the theme), and after using background: #none it will be grey).

How can I achieve resetting to default color without using deprecated functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this via adding and removing a class:

```
GtkStyleContext *context = gtk_widget_get_style_context (entry);
```

**adding:**

```
gtk_style_context_add_class (context, "newclass");
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (provider, 
".entry.newclass { background: #927373}", -1, NULL);
```

**removing:**

```
gtk_style_context_remove_class (context, "newclass");
```